# MIT AppInventor 2 how to show "loading" notifier

Tags: app-inventor

I have a block whose loading time is like 10seconds. It takes time because there is a shuffling process. I want to show a loading notifier while the block is loading.

I tried to add progress dialog just before calling the block but it did not show up. I guess the whole block is interpreted at once. It seems I need a kind of pause which will allow the screen to be loaded partially so that the notifier is shown.

I can do it by showing a choose dialog so that the block is loaded when the user chooses load but it does not look nice because the user must choose the load to continue.

Does anybody know a (better) way of doing it?

Comment: use a clock component, add your heavy procedure there and start the clock after showing the progress dialog

Answer (score 0):

You could have a button showing text like "loading" and then set the text color to your background color once the other block initializes.